# Javascript Alert pop up not working in IOS for phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have phonegap app build for android and IOS. The alert-box is working great in Android but I am not getting alert in Iphone. Please help.

This piece of code works good for droid:

```
else {
  navigator.notification.alert('Invalid Username or Password!');
}
```

Comment: Code looks right, so either the else{} is not being called because a if{} is found to be true, or you are possibly doing this call before PhoneGap is loaded. Can you offer any more insight or code?

Comment: @JasonDean: Else is called since its working in android, do you still more code details?

Comment: Else being called on Android does not necessarily mean it will be called on iOS. if (Platform == "iOS") would not call else on iOS (as a contrived pseudocode example). Yes, we need more info to figure anything out on this.

Comment: @JasonDean: I figured it out, I was not calling out the device ready trigger event so I cahnge he phonegap javascript file and it worked. bdw thanks for your feedback

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant when I said "or you are possibly doing this call before PhoneGap is loaded"

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like that, phonegap wasn't working with iOS and working with Android.

In my case, that happened because the phonegap.js is different from Android's to iOS, so I had to move my www folder to iOS app and keep the iOS phonegap.js instead of using Android phonegap.js

I did that by creating a "HelloWorld" iOS + Phonegap app and copying his phonegap.js to my actual app.

After that, Phonegap started to work again! See ya!